# capistrano not restarting, stopping but update is working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, deployment, mongrel

I recently changed machines, and had a few rough spots updating Rails. The server itself stayed as it was. Everything seemed to be fine, but not capistrano. When I make changes and update SVN, running

```
cap deploy
```

the correct new version of the repository is placed on the server. The logging in the terminal running capistrano shows nothing out of the ordinary, but evidently no restart actually takes place because the server continues to run. Running

```
cap deploy:restart
```

Produces

```
Dans-iMac:rebuild apple$ cap deploy:restart
  * executing `deploy:restart'
  * executing `accelerator:smf_restart'
  * executing `accelerator:smf_stop'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' svcadm disable /network/mongrel/urbanistica-production"
    servers: ["www.urbanisti.ca"]
Password: 
    [www.urbanisti.ca] executing command
    command finished
  * executing `accelerator:smf_start'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' svcadm enable -r /network/mongrel/urbanistica-production"
    servers: ["www.urbanisti.ca"]
    [www.urbanisti.ca] executing command
    command finished
  * executing `accelerator:restart_apache'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' svcadm refresh svc:/network/http:cswapache2"
    servers: ["www.urbanisti.ca"]
    [www.urbanisti.ca] executing command
    command finished
```

But no evident change takes place. What might be going on? The Mongrel log on the server shows no changes whatever: it's still running the older version that predates the update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem would seem to be in your custom (or, at least non-built-in) restart task. The task `accelerator:smf_restart`, and associated `smf_stop` and `smf_start` tasks, that are being called are not part of the standard Capistrano suite. Did you write those tasks yourself or are they from a Capistrano extension? If so, what extension?

If you can post a link to that extension, or post your Capfile if you wrote them youself, that would help people figuring out more specifically what's going wrong.